# Retrieve auto ID from FireBase JSON swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase

I am uploading names to a table in FireBase using a loop which adds them using the `childByAutoID()` method like this:

```
for dependent in dependentsArray
    {
         let dependentName = dependent.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

         CURRENT_USER_DEPENDENTS_URL.childByAutoId().setValue(["name" : dependentName])
    }
```

which then looks like this in my dashboard:

[image]

I then observe the dependent table like so:

```
CURRENT_USER_DEPENDENTS_URL.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot.value)
        self.dependentsJSON = snapshot.value as? [String : [String : String]]

        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            print(error.description)
    })
```

The `print` statement in the code above produces this JSON dictionary:

```
{
    "-KH3Cg0KFvMNEULYUezv" =     {
        name = one;
    };
    "-KH3Cg0LeTs54nbYonmv" =     {
        name = two;
    };
    "-KH3Cg0LeTs54nbYonmw" =     {
        name = three;
    };
    "-KH3Cg0LeTs54nbYonmx" =     {
        name = four;
   };
}
```

Very simply put **I would like to be able to obtain the UIDs of each dependent from this JSON dictionary** so i can then create an array of dependent UIDs in `NSUserDefaults` as well as sort the JSON dictionary like this:

```
    if let firstName = self.dependentsJSON?["-KH3Cg0LeTs54nbYonmx"]?["name"] {
        print(firstName)
}
```

*Side note:*
I can save the UIDs at the time when they are created and added to the database but the fact is the UIDs need to be obtained at run time incase a user ever uninstalls the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following

```
var idList = [String]()

CURRENT_USER_DEPENDENTS_URL.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    //print(snapshot.value)
    self.dependentsJSON = snapshot.value as? [String : [String : String]]

    for dependent in self.dependentsJSON{
         idList.append(dependent.key)
    }

    }, withCancelBlock: { error in
        print(error.description)
})
```

Then you would access the values

```
if let firstName = self.dependentsJSON?[idList[0]]?["name"] {
    print(firstName)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do this:

```
var keys = Array(self.dependantsJSON.keys)
```

It's been a while since I worked with swift but I'm pretty sure you can grab all the keys from the returned snapshot and create an array from them.

Comment: im surprised i didnt think of this earlier. thank you!